# KeyError when trying to access ['style'] using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to access the style of a DIV element on a page using Beautiful Soup 4 but I keep getting a key error. I know the styles are definitely there because I can inspect them using the inspector in the browser and I can see styles for the DIV with class "header large border first". (see the attached image)

Here is my code;

```
url = 'https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/595743-sas-red-notice'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
header_image_style = soup.find("div", class_="header large border first")['style']
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong can anyone help?

Here is an image of the DIV with styles;

[image: Inspecting the DIV with inspector]

Comment: No, the `div` tag has no `style` attribute. I don't see any tag with `style` attribute

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply @buran. I'm confused, if you look at the screenshot on the bottom on the right you can see the styles for that class on the DIV. I thought this was the way to access them, no?

Comment: Obviously you are confused. In this case the styles are defined in [`style` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) - also visible on your screenshot - 3 lines above your `div` tag

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful soup does not analyze the contents in style tags or in linked style sheets unfortunately, so it will be difficult to retrieve that value since we will need to handle parsing the css on our own.

The value we are looking for is contained within the document's style tag, so we can get the contents of the style tag and parse it for ourselves to get the value. Here's a working example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cssutils
import requests

url = 'https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/595743-sas-red-notice'

response = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# get the style tag contents
style_str = soup.find("style").text

# parse the tag's contents
rules = cssutils.parseString(style_str)

# find the first rule that applies to "div.header.large.first"
rule = next(filter(lambda x: x.selectorText == "div.header.large.first", rules))

# get the backgroundImage property
background_property = rule.style.backgroundImage

# Cut out the start of the text that says "url(" and ")"
img_url = background_property[4:-1]

print(img_url)
```

You will need to `pip install cssutils` in order for this example to work.